# Appending lists to a global list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to generate a list of permutations (also lists) by appending a global list as each permutation is generated.  I can tell the permutations are being generated properly by printing each after it is generated.  However, after the function is called my global list only contains the original list for each time a permutation was generated by the function.

```
    array = []

    def perms(a, k):
        if (k == len(a)):
            global array
            array.append(a)
            print(a) #perms function is working properly
        else:
             for i in range(k, len(a)):
                     a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]
                     perms(a, k+1)
                     a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]


    perms([1,2,3,4], 0)

    #only prints the original list for each time a perm was generated
    for i in array: print(i)
```

When I am printing at the bottom it is showing array = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], ...]

It seems like my global list array can only see the perms parameter a in the scope it was called in.

How would this be done properly?

Comment: You are modifying the same list over and over, so your later modifications undo the earlier ones.  Is there a reason you're not using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, lists are mutable. So when you call `perms(a, k+1)` inside `perms`, you're ending up with the exact same instance of `a` inside the recursive call. Consider this example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> print a
[[4, 5, 6]]
>>> b.append(7)
>>> print a
[[4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

As you can see, editing the `b` list directly also edits the `b` that was appended to the `a` list, because both `b` and `a[0]` are referencing the exact same object:

```
>>> b is a[0]
True
```

You don't see this behavior with strings, which are immutable:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = "hi"
>>> a.append(b)
>>> print a
['hi']
>>> b = "blah"
>>> print a
['hi']

>>> b is a[0]
False
```

You can fix the issue in your code by passing a copy of the `a` list into the recursive call, like this:

```
perms(a[:], k+1)
```